# Rspec/Capybara not finding content in my rendered partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, haml

I have this code for my `views/board_games/index.html.haml`

```
.row
    %ul
        = render @board_games
```

This is my `views/board_games/_board_games.html.haml`

```
%li
    %a{href: board_game_path(board_game.id) }
    %h5.text-center
        %strong
            = board_game.name
    %img.image-center{ src: board_game.image_url }
```

In my specs I have

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Board Game Pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Index page" do
    let(:bg1) { FactoryGirl.create(:board_game) }
    let(:bg2) { FactoryGirl.create(:board_game) }

    before { visit board_games_path }

    it { should have_content(bg1.name) }
    it { should have_content(bg2.name) }
  end
end
```

This test fails to pass even though I can see the content on the actual page. I've determined that its not following the `= render @board_games`. How can I get capybara/rspec to find the content there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is about `let`.

`let` is lazy. It won't do anything until you call it. In your case, you actually called `let` defined methods in the expectation. At that time, `let` creates the records for you, but it's late as the view is rendered, so no record to show.

The solution is to use `let!` instead of `let` if you want something persisted in db at first.

```
let!(:bg1) { FactoryGirl.create(:board_game) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not using Capybara there. You are probably using the "mock the server" pattern, where RSpec merely follows the routes and hits the same server-side action as a real web server would have.

(If you are, you shouldn't be, because without advanced JS Capybara is a waste of time.)

If you indeed don't use Capybara, turn on `render_views`, so RSpec won't stub out the actual template rendering step.